# sorting a filtered table as computed property

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, vue-material

I have a md-table in which I can filter the rows by the name of course, the filter works fine but as soon as I click on on the column name, the rows are not sorted

you should be able to sort them like in this sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/n7l7o742qm?module=App.vue

but if you try my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-search-and-empty-state-forked-6bb48?file=/App.vue

the sort functionality won't work

HTML

```
<md-table
  v-model="filteredRepetitions"
  md-sort="corso"
  md-sort-order="asc"
  md-card
  md-fixed-header
>
  <md-table-toolbar>
    <h1 class="md-title">With auto select and alternate headers</h1>
    <md-field md-clearable class="md-toolbar-section-end">
      <md-input placeholder="Search by course..." v-model="search"/>
    </md-field>
  </md-table-toolbar>


  <md-table-row
    class="md-primary"
    slot="md-table-row"
    slot-scope="{ item }"
  >
    <md-table-cell md-label="Corso" md-sort-by="corso">{{ item.corso }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Docente" md-sort-by="docente">{{ item.docente }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Data" md-sort-by="timeSlot.data">{{ item.timeSlot.data }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell
      md-label="Fascia oraria"
      md-sort-by="timeSlot.fasciaOraria"
    >{{ item.timeSlot.fasciaOraria }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Stato" md-sort-by="stato">{{ item.stato }}</md-table-cell>
  </md-table-row>
</md-table>
```

JS

```
const toLower = text => text.toString().toLowerCase();
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            repetitions2: [
                {
                    corso: 'Programmazione 3',
                    docente: 'Liliana Aridissono',
                    timeSlot: {
                        fasciaOraria: '15:00-16:00',
                        data: '2020-09-17'
                    },
                    stato: 'attiva'
                },
                {
                    corso: 'Python',
                    docente: 'Marco Amedura',
                    timeSlot: {
                        fasciaOraria: '17:00-18:00',
                        data: '2020-03-17'
                    },
                    stato: 'noattiva',
                },
                {
                    corso: 'Matematica Discreta',
                    docente: 'Vincenzo Bellomo',
                    timeSlot: {
                        fasciaOraria: '16:00-17:00',
                        data: '2020-02-17'
                    },
                    stato: 'noattiva',
                },
                {
                    corso: 'Algoritmi',
                    docente: 'Patti Viviana',
                    timeSlot: {
                        fasciaOraria: '16:00-17:00',
                        data: '2020-10-17'
                    },
                    stato: 'attiva',
                },
                {
                    corso: 'Analisi',
                    docente: 'Pinco Pallo',
                    timeSlot: {
                        fasciaOraria: '18:00-19:00',
                        data: '2020-10-26'
                    },
                    stato: 'attiva',
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    computed: {
        filteredRepetitions: {
            get: function () {
                return this.repetitions2.filter(item => toLower(item.corso).includes(toLower(this.search)))
            },
            set: function (array) {
               // what should i say?
            }
        }
    },
}
```

BONUS QUESTION:
is it possible not to filter only for a particular attribute (for instance now I can filter only by course name)

Comment: You would only need a setter when you're trying to assign something to a computed property, which you don't seem to be doing (you're not assigning to `filteredRepetitions` anywhere in your code. Could you explain the expected functionality? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://vuematerial.io/components/table reading from the documentation it's possible to sort the table by pressing the column name, I guess this is due to the fact that I'm passing to the v-model a computed property which doesn't work well with the sort functionality of that component

Comment: Nope, computed work just fine as table sources and they can be ordered, filtered anyway you like. Also, as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-mdtable-sorting-filtering-e45np?file=/src/App.vue) you can edit the items in computed and Vue doesn't lose track. Your question seems a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Let's forget Y (which is [documented here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)), and focus on X for a second. Please define in clear what you're trying to achieve. If necessary, provide a [mcve] containing the problem.

Comment: I want to be able to sort the table depending on which column label I click https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-search-and-empty-state-forked-6bb48?file=/App.vue here the sand box, if you press any header, the rows are not sorted

Comment: The sandbox I linked above already does it, but not when clicking the headers (because you made your request after I posted it). First, update your question so that anyone wanting to answer it doesn't have to reach the comment above to find out what you actually want. It should be crystal clear from question. Second, I'd advise you to look at the code I provided and try to map the click event yourself. If others do it for you, you'll just delay learning. And, if you plan on coding, you'll need this time and time again. What you want is to change `reversed` and `searchColumn` on header click.

Comment: sorry I did see the sandbox, although you are able to sort the table by clicking the checkbox, I'm not trying to achieve that, I updated my question and as you can see in the first example just by clicking on the column label like 'Id' 'Name' etc.. you are able to sort the table by those particular criteria, which is achieved by "md-sort-by" in the "md-table-cell" component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with `<md-table>` a bit more, it turns out you don't actually need computed for `sortColumn` and `sortOrder`. You do need to use `.sync` modifier, though, as outlined in the docs.

***And*** you have to provide an *empty **setter*** (`md-table` will try to assign to the computed when it's changed). However, you don't need to assign anything, as `sortColumn` and `sortOrder` change accordingly and your getter reacts to those changes.

I added a `watch` which resets `sortOrder` every time the `sortColumn` is changed - other than that, it's pretty clean.

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-mdtable-sorting-filtering-forked-6v3fk?file=/src/App.vue).

Relevant code:

```js
import { sortBy } from 'lodash-es';

{ 
  data: () => ({
    searchTerm: "",
    searchColumn: "corso",
    sortColumn: "corso",
    sortOrder: "asc",
    items: [...]
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(
        item => this.searchColumn
          .split(".")
          .reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], item)
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
      );
    },
    orderedItems: {
      get: function() {
        return sortBy(this.filteredItems, this.sortColumn);
      },
      set: () => {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    sortColumn() {
      this.$nextTick(() => (this.sortOrder = "desc"));
    }
  },
}
```